# If Heisenberg's uncertainty principle is an inherent property of nature, why does Heisenberg's microscope indicate an observation-based experiment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I am aware of this [SE-Answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/534614/what-does-heisenbergs-uncertainty-principle-tell-about-nature?answertab=votes#tab-top), however, I am eager to know why Heisenberg himself introduced an *observation-based* experiment to demonstrate his intuitive explanation of his uncertainty formula. Does his [microscope experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg%27s_microscope) show that Heisenberg initially believed that his uncertainty principle had been a measurement effect rather than something inherent?

On the other hand, we know that, according to special relativity, the physical form or path of a fast-moving object is complicatedly deformed due to the non-simultaneous arrival of the signals emitted from the different parts of the object if we tend to *observe* the object. However, we rule out those observation effects by *imagining* the real form or the motion path rather than observing them. In this case, no one, rationally enough, asserts that since non-simultaneity is an inherent property of nature, the so-called observable deformations are all inherent and they rule the reality!

Does the same happen for judging Heisenberg's uncertainty formula? Is there any interpretation of quantum mechanics in which case there is a certain path for any fundamental particle and Heisenberg's principle is a measurement effect contrary to the Copenhagen interpretation?

Comment: To the asker: Please focus this question on *one specific question*: The historical question of whether Heisenberg initially believed the HUP to be a measurement effect is a different question than whether or not an interpretation of QM exists where it *is* a measurement effect, and probably better suited to [hsm.SE].

Comment: The point is that there is no distinction between physical properties and measured properties. It is an inherent property of nature that the numbers we use in physics are derived from observation, and have nothing to do with unholy metaphysics, that the numbers exist independent of observation and measurement. This is well established in both relativity and quantum mechanics, and shows that a "certain path" is a metaphysical, meaningless, concept in classical mechanics which is now also empirically proven false.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the Bohmian mechanics/Bohm interpretation of quantum physics. I don't know the technical details of but it is deterministic like Classical Mechanics. The positions and momenta of particles are fixed, and the uncertainty principle is only a result of observation.

The reason it's not mainstream is probably because it requires the introduction of hidden variables (which are responsible for its deterministic nature). These hidden variables can't be observed and they are like an extra assumption. Physicists prefer the theories with the least assumptions explaining the observations.

There is also a similar interpretation of special relativity called the Lorentz-ether theory. Again, it is not possible to figure out the correct theory between this one and special relativity by observations (as they predict the same observations). Again, special relativity is preferred because it's more elegant and requires less assumptions.